How to preload hyphenation pattern for ecclesiasticlatin?
I have the following in my doc preamble:
\usepackage[main=spanish,ecclesiasticlatin]{babel}
\babelprovide[hyphenrules=liturgicallatin]{ecclesiasticlatin}

But latexmk returns the following error message:
principal.tex|55 warning| Package babel Warning: No hyphenation patterns were preloaded for the language 'latin' into the format. Please, configure your TeX system to add them and rebuild the format. Now I will use the patterns

I tried running fmtutil -sys --all already, but didn't solved the problem...
How can I get rid of the error?
The output of tlmgr info babel-latin is the following:
package:     babel-latin
category:    Package
shortdesc:   Babel support for Latin
longdesc:    The babel-latin package provides the babel languages latin, classiclatin, medievallatin, and ecclesiasticlatin. It also defines several useful shorthands as well as some modifiers for typographical fine-tuning.
installed:   Yes
revision:    59800
sizes:       src: 97k, doc: 189k, run: 53k
relocatable: No
cat-version: 4.0
cat-license: lppl1.3
cat-topics:  latin multilingual-addon
cat-contact-bugs: https://github.com/wehro/babel-latin/issues
cat-contact-repository: https://github.com/wehro/babel-latin
collection:  collection-langeuropean


depending how you installed texlive you basically need tlmgr install babel-latin  possibly via sudo and possibly using apt or yum or whatever instead of using tlmgr directly if you are using a linux packaged texlive

@DavidCarlisle, I installed babel-latin thru tlmgr already.  Yet, it still returns the same error.

@DavidCarlisle,  Could it be related to the settings from the $TEXMF* variable values?

you shouldn't have to set them.  how did you install tex, and what does tlmgr info babel-latin report?

It was a successful install.  I used the TeXLive installer.

well clearly it wasn't completely successful, but you have given no information, what scheme did you install? if you installed texlive-full then latin would be installed, you didn't say what tlmgr info babel-latin reports either

I used the small scheme.

rebuild the formats with fmtutil-sys --all  and check you have no local formats under your account check with kpsewhich --all  --engine=pdftex pdflatex.fmt

@DavidCarlisle, thanks for help.  I noticed that I needed to use lualatex and I was missing some other packages.
